# Should I add my /var file to conffiles?

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm making a file manager system for managing my projects. It needs to keep track of the next id for the next project (an integer). As the package upgrades it needs to keep this number.

As I understand, the best is that I create a file `/var/local/filesystem/next_id` with the integer in it. (My package is installed in `/usr/local`)

I have read about `conffiles` in the `DEBAIN` folder, should I add `/var/local/filesystem/next_id` or is that not common practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `/var/local/filesystem/next_id` actually in the package (or is it created in your package's postinst script or by your file manager program when it runs)?

If it **IS** in the package then add it to `conffiles`, to prevent it from being automatically over-written the next time the package is upgraded.  This will cause apt/dpkg to ask you what you want to do if the file has been modified when you upgrade - the usual install, keep, diff, or start a shell question.

If it **isn't** in the package then don't add it to `conffiles`.  There's no need.